# How to view the databases in Android Device?

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to view the database in my android device but as it an un-rooted device, I am unable to do so. I have implemented the following code in my DBAdapter class and am calling it at another activity.

**CODE :**

```
void exportDB() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + "com.example.facebook_integration"
                        + "//databases//" + "image_database.db";
                String backupDBPath = "//sdcard//FBDatabase";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

But the above code doesn't seem to work. I have already surfed well in Stackoverflow about this question(there are quiet a few) and also tried the adb commands but none of them has worked. Can you please tell me where am going wrong at the above code or an alternative to the above solution ? Help will be much appreciated guys.

Comment: I do have another doubt in viewing the SDCard contents in File Explorer. I am unable to view the sdcard contents in DDMS Filexplorer. I just need to retrieve the database to view it in SQLiteBrowser. How do i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump DB into SDcard and open into SQLite Manager o SQLite Database Tools:

```
    File f=new File("/data/data/yourapppackagename/databases/database");
                    FileInputStream fis=null;
                    FileOutputStream fos=null;

                    try
                    {
                      fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                      fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/folder/database.db");
                      while(true)
                      {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                      }
                      fos.flush();
                      Toast.makeText(getParent(), "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Toast.makeText(getParent(), "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        fos.close();
                        fis.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception ioe)
                      {}
                    }
```

Comment: Will give this a try and let ya know. Thanks for your effort manish.

Comment: you must add sdcard write and read  permission into your manifest.xml file.

Comment: I have added both the permissions in my manifest file but unable to confirm the existence the database file(i am not trying to view the database in my mobile) in my mobile. Also another doubt is that do i need to give only existing folder name in FileOutputStream or it will create the folder name that i type in ?

Comment: Here, in this path you must provide your database name: File("/data/data/yourapppackagename/databases/yourdatabasename") and then you create any random folder where you want to export this DB and then add all path to FileOutputStream(Folder path+"/yournewexportdatabasename")

Comment: Thanks Manish. Helped a lot.

Comment: Hey Manish,Should I add f.createNewFile() line after  new FileOutPutStream ? I can see the database in my mobile after i add the above mentioned  line but not able to see the database when i connect my phone to  PC. Isn't it weird ? I can see its existence in mobile but not on my PC. Any insights ??

Comment: what is the size of your database? if size>0 then it's successfully exported.

Comment: Its size is 20 KB !!! Thanks pal. But why am i unable to view it in my PC. I have stored the database in a folder named FBDatabase in external SD card. I can see the database file in mobile but the same folder shows nothing while connected to my PC ?? How can i retrieve the database cause i need to view it and make sure about the contents ?

Comment: you just import this Database file to your system using DDMS tools. below i show you one image. Have a look.

Answer (score 2):

[image: DDMS] you just select Database file and then export into your system.

Comment: Thanks Pal. I already knew this but it just didnt strike my mind to search deep in DDMS. Thanks a bunch though.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the output as your file backupDB does not physically exists.
File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath); - this will only create a logical file object, it may not be physically present.So you should call,

```
backupDB.createNewFile();
```

in order to physically create  a file.

Comment: Thanks nikvs. Much obliged.